# Product of invertible matrix and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am confused about this problem. Let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$ of dimension $m\leq k$ and $\{b_1,...,b_m\}$ is a basis of $S$. Now, given an invertible matrix $A$. I have a feeling the set $\cal P=\{Ab_1,...,Ab_m\}$ is also basis of $S$, but I don't now how to prove precisely. What I am sure is $\cal P$ is linear independent. But, how can we prove that $\cal P$ spans $S$ as well? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the subspace $\langle(1, 0)\rangle$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the invertible matrix corresponding to rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: OK, thanks. It turned out an elementary thing.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal P$ is guaranteed to be a basis for some subspace of dimension $m$ (by virtue of all vectors being linearly independent) but that subspace is not guaranteed to be $S$. If $\mathcal A$ maps vectors in $S$ into vectors in $S$ all is well and fine as I will elaborate a little more on but it could be that some $\mathcal A b_i$ is not in $S$ and then everything falls apart.

As an example let $c_1,..., c_{k - m}$* be for the vectors which do not lie in $S$ and define a map which $\mathcal A$ which switches $b_1 \leftrightarrow c_1$ and leaves everything else invariant. This map is invertible but $\mathcal P = \{c_1,b_2,..., b_m\}$ is not a basis for $S$.

If however $\mathcal A$ is a map such that $\mathcal A(S) = S$ (leaves the subspace invariant) then $\mathcal P$ will be a basis for the space by virtue of the fact that $m$ linealy independent vectors in an $m$ dimensional space is always a basis set.

EDIT. *I assume of course that this basis is independent of the basis of $S$ so that $\{b_1,..., b_m,c_1, ..., c_{k - m}\}$ is a basis for the complete space. Any single vector which is linearly of all the vectors in $S$ will also do.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Squid. I guessed that because actually I'd like to prove [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632638/sum-of-two-matrices)