# Sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $m<n$. Suppose that $H$ and $K$ be $m \times n$ and $n\times (n-m)$ matrices such that rank$(H)=m$, rank$(K)=n-m$, and $HK=0$. For fixed non singular symmetric matrix $A$ define
\begin{equation}
P=A^{-1}H^T(HA^{-1}H^T)^{-1}H\  \text{and} \ Q=K(K^TAK)^{-1}K^TA.
\end{equation}

I'd like to have $P+Q$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

It can be verified that $[H^T,A^{-1}K](P+Q)=[H^T,A^{-1}K].$ So, if $[H^T,A^{-1}K]$ is invertible then $P+Q=I$. However, it is quite difficult the invertibility of $[H^T,A^{-1}K]$. Therefore, I wonder  $P+Q=I$ not need to be true. Can anyone help me? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: By the way, is the matrix $A$ by chance also positive definite? If so, is it necessary to work with the orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $H$ with respect to the Euclidean inner product (spanned by the columns of $K$) and consider instead the $A$-orthogonal complement? In that case, you don't need to bother with the (non-)singularity of $[H^T,A^{-1}K]$.

Comment: Thanks @AlgebraicPavel. Yes, $A$ is positive semidefinite. I am sorry, I don't understand with your second question? Could you make me clearly please?

Comment: First, if it is nonsingular and semidefinite, then it is for sure definite. Second, you seem to work with orthogonal projectors in generalised inner products (induced by $A$ and $A^{-1}$), while for the space spanned by $K$ you consider the Euclidean inner product. My question was, if it is really necessary. But without more context (what is given, what is to be obtained) it is hard to guess.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. Actually, what given is only $H$ and $A$. I defined $K$ by a matrix such that $HK=0$. Therefore, I'd like to express $Q$ in term of $H$. Do I understand correctly your question?

Comment: Could you then instead of $K$ such that $HK=0$ consider $K$ such that $HAK=0$? Then, given $Q$, $P$ such that $P+Q=I$ would be simply $P=H^T(HAH^T)^{-1}HA$ (if I've put the formula correctly).

Comment: OK thank you very much for your suggestion. I'll think further about that.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: Great, It finally works if I consider $HAK=0$ and it can be proved manually. However, I am curious how can we see $P+Q=I$ easily using projection and its kernel?